# Stale props inside a method of a class-based component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

This is a spelling game. The user drags the correct letter over the dropzone. On drop, the function **checkIfLetterIsCorrect** is invoked and runs the checking process. When all dropzones are filled with the correct letter the app moves on to the next word and props and state or in sync.

This all works fine on a hard refresh. However, this component is inside a Semantic UI React modal, and when the modal is closed and reopened, and I set the game back up **this.props.currentWordLetters** is the correct value, but  when **checkIfLetterIsCorrect** is invoked, the value of **this.props.currentWordLetters** inside this method is of the value before the modal was closed. I checked with a console.log inside **ComponentWillUnmount** and the component is indeed unmounting when the modal is closed, so I don't see why the values inside **checkIfLetterIsCorrect** would be outdated as everything should be rendered like new. If somebody could point me in the right direction it would be a big help. Thank you.

```
class DropzoneContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            correctCounter: 0,
        };
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        console.log('unMounted')
    }

    checkIfLetterIsCorrect(e) {
        
        for (let i = 0; i < this.props.currentWordLetters.length; i++) {
            console.log(this.props.currentWordLetters, this.state.letters);
            if (
                this.props.currentWordLetters[i] ===
                    e.relatedTarget.innerText &&
                e.relatedTarget.innerText === e.target.innerText
            ) {
                e.relatedTarget.classList.remove('draggable');
                this.props.onCorrectLetter();
        

                this.setState({
                    correctCounter: this.state.correctCounter + 1,
                });
                if (this.state.correctCounter === this.props.currentWordLetters.length) {
                    this.setState({ correctCounter: 0 })
                    clearInterval(this.props.timer.current);
                    this.props.onTimerStop();

                    this.props.onRoundComplete();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
//...
```

Here is the entire component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import interact from 'interactjs';
import { Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Dropzone from '../dropzone/dropzone.component'

import {
    onCorrectLetter,
    onRoundComplete,
    onTimerStop,
} from '../../../../actions/phonicsGameActions';

class DropzoneContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            correctCounter: 0,
        };
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        console.log('unMounted')
    }

    checkIfLetterIsCorrect(e) {
        
        for (let i = 0; i < this.props.currentWordLetters.length; i++) {
            console.log(this.props.currentWordLetters, this.state.letters);
            if (
                this.props.currentWordLetters[i] ===
                    e.relatedTarget.innerText &&
                e.relatedTarget.innerText === e.target.innerText
            ) {
                e.relatedTarget.classList.remove('draggable');
                this.props.onCorrectLetter();
        

                this.setState({
                    correctCounter: this.state.correctCounter + 1,
                });
                if (this.state.correctCounter === this.props.currentWordLetters.length) {
                    this.setState({ correctCounter: 0 })
                    clearInterval(this.props.timer.current);
                    this.props.onTimerStop();

                    this.props.onRoundComplete();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        console.log("component mountedw " + this.props.currentWordLetters)
        // enable draggables to be dropped into this
interact(".inner-dropzone").dropzone({
    // only accept elements matching this CSS selector
    accept: ".draggable",
    // Require a 75% element overlap for a drop to be possible
    overlap: 0.75,
 
    // listen for drop related events:
 
    ondropactivate: function (event) {
      // add active dropzone feedback
      event.target.classList.add("drop-active");
    },
    ondragenter: function (event) {
      var draggableElement = event.relatedTarget;
      var dropzoneElement = event.target;
 
      // feedback the possibility of a drop
      dropzoneElement.classList.add("drop-target");
      draggableElement.classList.add("can-drop");
      //draggableElement.textContent = 'Dragged in'
    },
    ondragleave: function (event) {
      // remove the drop feedback style
 
      event.target.classList.remove("correct");
      event.target.classList.remove("incorrect");
      event.target.classList.remove("drop-target");
      event.relatedTarget.classList.remove("can-drop");
      event.target.classList.remove("test");
      //event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dragged out'
    },
    ondrop:  (event)=> {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      this.checkIfLetterIsCorrect(event)
 
 
    },
  
    ondropdeactivate: function (event) {
      // remove active dropzone feedback
      event.target.classList.remove("drop-active");
      event.target.classList.remove("drop-target");
      event.target.classList.remove("drop-target");
    },
 })
    }


    render() {
    
        return (
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Row style={{ justifyContent: 'space-evenly' }}>
                    {this.props.currentWordLetters.length > 1
                        ? this.props.currentWordLetters.map((zone) => (
                                <Dropzone
                                    key={zone}
                                    letter={zone}
                                    style={{
                                        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                                        width: '55px',
                                        height: '55px',
                                        border: 'dotted white 2px',
                                    }}
                                    className="inner-dropzone"
                                />
                          ))
                        : 'Loading Dropzone...'}
                </Grid.Row>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}



const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    onRoundComplete: () => dispatch(onRoundComplete()),
    onCorrectLetter: () => dispatch(onCorrectLetter()),
    onTimerStop: () => dispatch(onTimerStop()),
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    currentWordLetters: state.phonicsGameReducer.currentWordLetters,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DropzoneContainer);
```

Comment: Can you provide some code of the parent component?which is passing the props

Comment: Thanks for the response! The component is wrapped in a hoc (connect function from react-redux. All the props are coming from the store.

Comment: Maybe try resetting the State of redux store in componentWillUnmount,because you’re not resetting the state when the modal closes, so it’s going to take the old value i suppose